# strcat implementation

Tags: c, strcat

I tried to implement the strcat by myself, and I found the strcat implementation from [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcat) like this......but when I use it, there is segmentation fault.

What's wrong with the code below?

```
char *
strcat(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    size_t i,j;
    for (i = 0; dest[i] != '\0'; i++)
        ;
    for (j = 0; src[j] != '\0'; j++)
        dest[i+j] = src[j];
    dest[i+j] = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: The code seems fine. Are you sure you use it correctly? What's the "client code"?

Comment: Throw in a check for `dest` or `src` being null.

Comment: In Standard C, the library can do what it likes when either pointer is null; the behaviour is undefined.  Legitimate undefined behaviour does include 'working sanely'; it also includes 'crashing with a core dump' and 'removing every file on the machine that you have permission to remove'.  Don't risk it - don't call library functions with null pointers.

Comment: The question should be: "Why is Wikipedias strcat implementation wrong?". You should ask that on the wiki discussion page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Strcat). Besides, it's probably your client code (which may not even exist) that is broken.

Comment: Quite true, but when re-implementing a library function, particularly if one is reporting segmentation violations, checking for nulls and following the principle of least surprise would seem the appropriate thing to do.

Comment: That's an awful idea. Most invalid pointers aren't null, so this doesn't help in practice. And when you do detect a null pointer, what are you going to do with it? Abort the program? Because that's what would happen anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the code is okay.

Looks like you have a problem in the calling code.

Did you remember to allocate enough memory for the target string?

Comment: Especially for the null terminator.

Comment: +1, likely the OP is calling with a string constant as the destination parameter.

Answer (score 10):

I would strongly suggest using pointers rather than integer indexes, for fear of integer overflow. Even if `size_t` is the same number of bits as `char *`, you're *adding* indices where you wouldn't be adding pointers.

I guess that's more or less academical; if you're calling `strcat()` on multi-gigabyte strings you're probably in all sorts of trouble.

Here's a pointer-based version, for completeness' sake:

```
char *
my_strcat(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *rdest = dest;

    while (*dest)
      dest++;
    while (*dest++ = *src++)
      ;
    return rdest;
}
```

Sure, this does take another pointer's worth of space for the `rdest` return value, but I think that's a fine trade-off.

Also note that you can't legally define a function called `strcat()` in ordinary application code; that whole namespace (public functions with names starting with `str`) is reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

dest needs to have enough memory to accommodate the concatenation in this implementation.  In this implementation, it would have to be allocated by the caller.  You should also be sure both dest and src are null terminated.  If dest does not have enough memory, this will overwrite memory that could be used by something else.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine with me, I have check it.

```
    #include "stdio.h"


    char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src)

    {

    size_t i,j;

    for (i = 0; dest[i] != '\0'; i++)

        ;

    for (j = 0; src[j] != '\0'; j++)

        dest[i+j] = src[j];

    dest[i+j] = '\0';

    return dest;

}


void main(void)

{

    char a[10]={"abc"}, b[10]={"def"};

    strcat(a,b);

    printf("%s",a);

    getchar();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate enough memory for the destination string.. ie atleast (length of source string + 1).

Comment: hmm .. nothing new to earlier answers, is there?