# C: How to append/concatenate 'x' spaces to a string

Tags: c, string, concatenation, spaces

I want to add a variable number of spaces to a string in C, and wanted to know if there is a standard way to do it, before I implement it by myself.

Until now I used some ugly ways to do it:

- Please assume that before I called any of the below functions, I took care to have enough memory allocated for the spaces I want to concatenate

This is one way I used:

```
add_spaces(char *dest, int num_of_spaces) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < num_of_spaces ; i++) {
        strcat(dest, " ");
    }
}
```

This one is a better in performance, but also doesn't look standard:

```
add_spaces(char *dest, int num_of_spaces) {
    int i;
    int len = strlen(dest);
    for (i = 0 ; i < num_of_spaces ; i++) {
        dest[len + i] = ' ';
    }
    dest[len + num_of_spaces] = '\0';
}
```

So, do you have any standard solution for me, so I don't reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Have you looked at memset? I just ask you to take care with buffer overflows.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488563/strcat-implementation). All tries can convert to straightforward algorithms and you can boost the them performance with assumptions and optimizations. The main issue is too grant `dest` enough space to receive new characters.

Comment: I assume that there is enough spaces for the characters in the destination. The question is whether there is a standard way to generate such string of spaces in one command

Comment: As others pointed out, I believe `memset` is the answer.

Comment: @user3322273 you first init your `dest` array by `memset` like  `memset( dest, ' ', sizeof(dest));`. So after that you not even need to add space or your implementation also optimized.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do

```
add_spaces(char *dest, int num_of_spaces) {
    int len = strlen(dest);
    memset( dest+len, ' ', num_of_spaces );   
    dest[len + num_of_spaces] = '\0';
}
```

But as @self stated, a function that also gets the maximum size of dest (including the `'\0'` in that example) is safer:

```
add_spaces(char *dest, int size, int num_of_spaces) {
    int len = strlen(dest);
    // for the check i still assume dest tto contain a valid '\0' terminated string, so len will be smaller than size
    if( len + num_of_spaces >= size ) {
        num_of_spaces = size - len - 1;
    }  
    memset( dest+len, ' ', num_of_spaces );   
    dest[len + num_of_spaces] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Unsafe, total size of dest is missing.

Comment: @self any version of `add_spaces()` that only takes these two arguments depends on the caller to check for appropriate sizes. I will add a solutiion that also taks the maximum size.

Answer (score 4):

```
void add_spaces(char *dest, int num_of_spaces) {
    sprintf(dest, "%s%*s", dest, num_of_spaces, "");
}
```

Comment: could you comment on what `%*s` does?

Comment: @NathanFellman Take a width that is specified in the argument.

Comment: It may be undefined behavior this is in violation of the restrict of a C99 to be exact, but probably okay.

Comment: Is there also a way to do it with any other character? E.g. I want to create a string of 'x' dashes in one command.

Comment: @user3322273 Function to do it in standard function probably does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

> Please assume that before I called any of the below functions, I took
>   care to have enough memory allocated for the spaces I want to
>   concatenate

So in `main` suppose you declared your array like `char dest[100]` then initialize your string with speces.

like

```
char dest[100];
memset( dest,' ',sizeof(dest));
```

So you not need even `add_spaces(char *dest, int num_of_spaces)`.

Comment: A `0` set after the spaces would be nice. Also, what does your answer bring that isn't in the answer from @Ingo above, posted 28 min before yours?