# How would I concate 2 strings into a one in assembly? (NASM)

Tags: string, assembly, x86, nasm, string-concatenation

I have recently started learning assembly. I am trying to concate two 32 byte strings into  a final one that is preallocated as 64 bytes.

```
section .data
     string1 db "static string",0
section .bss
     user_inputed_string resb 32
     concated_string resb 64
```

I am trying to achieve the strings concated in a way the user inputted one goes first and the static one second: **concated_string = user_inputed_string + string1**

I have looked the internet for solutions and none even seems to be valid syntax for NASM.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62132357/how-does-this-pointer-based-strcat-work-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First copy the user inputted string to the output buffer. I assume it is a zero-terminated string.

```
  mov edi, concated_string       ; Address of output buffer
  mov esi, user_inputed_string   ; Address of input buffer
more1:
  mov al, [esi]
  inc esi
  mov [edi], al
  inc edi
  cmp al, 0
  jne more1
```

Then copy the static string but do overwrite the terminating zero from the first copy:

```
  dec edi                        ; Removes the zero
  mov esi, string1
more2:
  mov al, [esi]
  inc esi
  mov [edi], al
  inc edi
  cmp al, 0
  jne more2                      ; This zero needs to stay
```

You can replace `mov al, [esi]` `inc esi` by `lodsb`, and you can replace `mov [edi], al` `inc edi` by `stosb`.

Comment: @urula: As an optimization on this, you have extra space reserved right after your `user_inputed_string` buffer, so you could append to it right there, instead of copying it first.  Also, since the string you're appending is a constant, you could use its length to memcpy it (with `rep movsb`) instead of its zero-terminator to strcpy it with a lodsb/stosb loop.